# Calories burnt while rope jumping?

Tags: calories, jump-rope

How many calories are burnt during a rope jumping exercise? How can we calculate the amount of calories burnt?

I am performing 100 rope skips in around 7-8 minutes and doing 1000 rope skips in total.

Comment: your weight x (distance of jump/time= km/h) = joules burned for one jump

Comment: @Avdol Energy is mass times acceleration times distance, not mass times velocity (1 Joule is not 1kg m/s). Not that the physics definition of work is a particularly good estimation of calories burned during exercise - under that definition, running on a treadmill or doing any isometric exercise burns 0 calories.

Answer (score 1):

[From the July 2004 issue of the *Harvard Health Letter*](https://www.health.harvard.edu/diet-and-weight-loss/calories-burned-in-30-minutes-of-leisure-and-routine-activities), for 30 minutes of jumping rope:

- 125-pound (56.6 kg) person: 300 calories
- 155-pound (70.3 kg) person: 372 calories
- 185-pound (83.9 kg) person: 444 calories

The figures are deceptively accurate, but perhaps you can use them as a starting point. They all revolve around 5 calories per minute of activity.

The 'Harvard figures' (for lack of a better name) are also useful for comparison. They put jumping rope in the same league as running and swimming.

Re:

> How can we calculate the amount of calories burnt?

In my view, counting skips is one of the worst ways of doing so (imagine counting strokes on front crawl, or steps on running). Weight and duration of exercise are much more reliable factors.

Your question does not really ask whether jumping rope is a 'good way' of burning calories, but just in case: I think it is, and also think it has many, many more advantages and benefits.

Answer (score 0):

A person burns 200-300 calories on average in a 15-minute workout, but it depends upon the weight and intensity of skipping.